# Azure DevOps Pull Request checker triggered by changes outside from included path

Tags: github, azure-devops, pipeline

I have a PR checker triggered when someone creates a pull request in Github. My yml file is on GitHub and the pipeline is on Azure DevOps. So, here is my trigger:

PR check

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - src/Web

trigger: none
```

But, when someone makes changes in other directories that are not included in the path above, let's say in `src/API` or `docs` it triggers the pipeline and runs a build check. It's not supposed to be checked as I have another pipeline for it.

Can someone point out where the error is?

Comment: I am running into the same situation, were you able to find a resolution?

Comment: Hi @Grim, I'm not sure what caused this but this issue was resolved by itself without me doing anything. Maybe there was a bug or something occur in Azure. For me, it was around 2 weeks before it was resolved.